# How to Import a .bak file using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, import

I have no knowledge on MySQL and I have received a .bak file from one of my customer and he asked me to "import" this file using MySQL.
I installed MysQL Community Server free download which installs MySQL Command Line Client.  Now I don't know how to Import this .bak file and can't read the necessary data that I need.

I tried installation of MySQL EE free trial as well but it doesn't give me anything that I can invoke the DB GUI so I can import the .bak file either.

I'm frustrated now and can't go anywhere.  Can you please help ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is in the `.bak` file? That file extension has no meaning in the mySQL world. Take a peek, maybe it contains mySQL statements.

Comment: Are you certain this isn't a MSSQL (Microsoft SQL) *.bak file?  That's the default extension we use on our MSSQL backups.  My MySQL backups I always .tar.gz as part of the backup process.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156279/how-to-import-a-sql-server-bak-file-into-mysql

Comment: Actually, .bak files DO have a meaning in the MySQL world.  They are created during automatic recovery of MyISAM tables - see the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-start.html

Answer (score 1):

`.bak` file is a sql server backup.

This is how to restore it: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Then import it to mysql.