# How to restore .bak file in MySQL server?

Tags: mysql

I used restore command to restore a `.bak` file in MySQL Server, but I got an error as its no longer valid, it's only allowed to server version 5.5.0. Currently I'm using version 5.7.13.

Comment: Those **aren't** SQL Server versions ..... sounds more like **MySQL** versions .... are you **SURE* you're using (Microsoft) **SQL Server**??? Otherwise please re-tag your question to the actual database system you're using!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for edit, its MYSQL

Comment: Have you followed the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156279/how-to-import-a-sql-server-bak-file-into-mysql - what is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the `.bak` file into SQL Server and then use [mysql migration toolkit](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).